# PySpark - How to check whether an object {RDD,DF,List etc,.} is distributed or not

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a solution to check whether an object data is distributed on the cluster or the whole data of the object is located on driver. Object can be anything like RDD, DataFrame or especially list object.

This will help me to optimise the spark job execution time.

Comment: df.isLocal() https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.isLocal

Comment: My DataFrame returns false, which means the data is on the worker node right?

Comment: yes. You can also check the spark UI in a browser